# How to Make a VBScript Timer

Tags: vbscript, timer

I need to have a timer appear in a message box, coded in vbs. The message box needs to be in the bottom left corner of the screen, just above the start menu. It needs to not be able to exit, meaning it cannot be listed on the task bar (hopefully) and have no minimise/exit buttons. It needs to stay on top of all the other windows. It also needs to start at 20 minutes, counting down in seconds. I hope someone can help me with this - it's for a computer lab.

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: Could you please show your code? What did you try?

Comment: you could possibly do this with an [HTA](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2007/03/25/html-applications-htas.aspx), although possibly not the "stay on top" requirement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like that :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,ws,nMinutes,nSeconds,sMessage
Title = "Counting Down to Shutdown"
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
nMinutes = 20
nSeconds = 0
sMessage = "<font color=Red size=2><b>Counting Down to Shutdown"
'Open a chromeless window with message
with HTABox("lightBlue",100,250,0,630)
    .document.title = "Counting Down Notification to Shutdown"
    .msg.innerHTML = sMessage
    do until .done.value or (nMinutes + nSeconds < 1)
        .msg.innerHTML = sMessage & "<br>" & nMinutes & ":" & Right("0"&nSeconds, 2) _
        & " remaining</b></font><br>"
        wsh.sleep 1000 ' milliseconds
        nSeconds = nSeconds - 1
        if nSeconds < 0 then 
            if nMinutes > 0 then
                nMinutes = nMinutes - 1
                nSeconds = 59
            end if
        end if
    loop
    .done.value = true
    .close
end with
ws.Popup "TIME IS OVER !","5",Title,0+48 'Afficher un Popup durant 5 secondes puis on quitte le script
'Command="cmd /c Shutdown.exe -s -t 30 -c " & DblQuote("Sauvegarder votre Travail car l'ordinateur va rebooter dans 30 secondes")
'Executer = WS.Run(Command,0,False) 
'*****************************************************************
Function HTABox(sBgColor, h, w, l, t)
    Dim IE, HTA, sCmd, nRnd
    randomize : nRnd = Int(1000000 * rnd)
    sCmd = "mshta.exe ""javascript:{new " _
    & "ActiveXObject(""InternetExplorer.Application"")" _
    & ".PutProperty('" & nRnd & "',window);" _
    & "window.resizeTo(" & w & "," & h & ");" _
    & "window.moveTo(" & l & "," & t & ")}"""
    with CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        .Run sCmd, 1, False
        do until .AppActivate("javascript:{new ") : WSH.sleep 10 : loop
        end with  'WSHShell
        For Each IE In CreateObject("Shell.Application").windows
            If IsObject(IE.GetProperty(nRnd)) Then
                set HTABox = IE.GetProperty(nRnd)
                IE.Quit
                HTABox.document.title = "HTABox"
                HTABox.document.write _
                "<HTA:Application contextMenu=no border=thin " _
                & "minimizebutton=no maximizebutton=no sysmenu=no SHOWINTASKBAR=no >" _
                & "<body scroll=no style='background-color:" _
                & sBgColor & ";font:normal 10pt Arial;" _
                & "border-Style:inset;border-Width:3px'" _
                & "onbeforeunload='vbscript:if not done.value then " _
                & "window.event.cancelBubble=true:" _
                & "window.event.returnValue=false:" _
                & "done.value=true:end if'>" _
                & "<input type=hidden id=done value=false>" _
                & "<center><span id=msg>&nbsp;</span><br>" _
                & "<input type=button id=btn1 value=' OK ' "_
                & "onclick=done.value=true><center></body>"
                HTABox.btn1.focus
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
        MsgBox "HTA window not found."
        wsh.quit
End Function
'*****************************************************************
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. My system administrator loves it. I've already written a script so that when the time is up the computer restarts. I hope it doesn't take too long to implement on all of the school lab's 50 PC's!

Comment: So, if you found it that is useful, so,you should vote and accept on it !

Comment: Wait - can a "log off" button be added to this?

Comment: What's the aim to add a log off button ?, explain more your purpose !

Comment: It's meant to be a part of a series of bat files that let our school pc's run semi-automatically. The Admin account has been hidden and the login screen has already been programed to say "Click the user kiosk to login." This lets the students to end their session early.